# How to try Lock-Modify-Unlock on VisualSVN server?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

We have a year using VisualSVN server, TortoiseSVN and ankhSVN plug-in to handle our source control with the style "Copy-Modify-Merge".

Now we want to try by ourself the style "Lock-Modify-Unlock" because we want to have our own opinions of this 2 styles.

What do we need to do is configure our repository to require locks for the existing projects and any projects that will be added in the future. We have seen the documentation on svn:needs-lock but we don't understand how to use this to move our shop to Lock-Modify-Unlock. We don't see a way to do it on the server or where to do it on the clients.

Can anyone please give us the "for dummies" explanation of how to set up VisualSVN server as well as our client machines to require locking for the existing projects and newly added projects?

NOTE:
We have read this commnets a lot but we still wan't to try the style.
[How do I reconfigure VisualSVN server from Copy-Modify-Merge to Lock-Modify-Unlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877485/how-do-i-reconfigure-visualsvn-server-from-copy-modify-merge-to-lock-modify-unlo)

Comment: There are two links in the answer to the question you cite that explain how to configure `svn:needs-lock`. What part of that information do you not understand? (And why in the world would you want to make this change on your entire repository to *see if you like it* rather than just testing on a small project? *Let's chance screwing up every single bit of our work product just to play around with something that everyone on the entire planet says we should not do, so we can make up our own minds.* seems like really poor decision making to me.)

Comment: Why the change? we know a lot of people doesn't like this old style, we read a lot, but the decision was not only mine, the whole team. In fact the other projects are closed, we are working only with one, your idea is good, we can implement it on only new projects, anyway it doesn't matter to us, I think we can change back to the other style right?

yes, we are courious and we want to make uo our own minds. We want to try it by our self so we can talk about this 2 styles with reason and not just repeating what others say. I think it is nothothing wrong with that.

Comment: "Let's chance screwing up every single bit of our work product just to play around with something that everyone on the entire planet says we should not do, so we can make up our own minds" we didn't said that, there was a lot of reasons and we was talking about this change a lot, i'm not sure why you assume we took this decision in one minute.

We didn't explained why in the world we want to do this because in the rules stackoverflow said to be concise and direct.

Comment: Well once explained that and returning to what is really important to us, in the first link you mention, it say to use needs-lock. we already read about that but how to apply it to all new files automatically? in the second link it only say what is needs-look (we already know what it is) but how to apply it to all new files automatically?

What I have to do in in VisualSVN server? if fact if someone can tells us please where to do it? in which menu, button or where is the config file. We can google later HOW to do it. We are totally lost.

Thank you guys for your time.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no *menu or button*. You'd have to use a pre-commit hook on the repository itself. You should spend some time reading the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) - it's free, written by some of the development team, and updated regularly. See in particular Chapter 3 *Advanced Topics, Locking*, and Chapter 5  *Repository Administration, Creating and Configuring Your Repository*, subsection *Implementing Repository Hooks*.

Comment: Got it thx, so we have to add hooks on every repository / context menu / properties / hooks, manualy right? that's a good clue. Thank you very much, we will look more about this.

Comment: BTW we read the book but we did't undarstand it. But now we know what we have to do, thx.